# Does AppleScript have an equivalent for the conditional (ternary) operator?

Tags: applescript, ternary-operator

Being familiar with programming, I am missing the ability to assign variables with ternary operators (i.e "set the variable to `x` if something is true, otherwise set it to `y`").  I'm thinking of something like:

```
set my_string to (if a is 0 return "" else return " - substring")
```

This of course doesn't work, and I haven't found anything similar yet.  Would there be another way to achieve this with applescript?

Comment: For what it's worth, this operator's name is the "conditional operator". It happens to be **a** ternary operator, but it is not **the** ternary operator, because while it is currently the only ternary operator, there is nothing stopping someone from inventing another ternary operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like AppleScript doesn't support the conditional operator but you can use list with two elements for that purpose. Of course, it's not very elegant in general:

```
set my_string to item (((a is 0) as integer) + 1) of {"", " - substring"}
```

And there is another way: you can use shell script

```
set b to (do shell script "test " & a & " -eq 0 && echo 'is 0' || echo 'is not 0'")
```

How could I forget this? :)

And in your case it will be even more simple (because an empty string will be returned if there is no echo at all).

```
set b to (do shell script "test " & a & " -eq 0 || echo '- substring'")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if a is 0 then
    set my_string to ""
else
    set my_string to " - substring"
end if
```

or

```
set a to 7

set my_string to my subTern(a)

on subTern(aLocalVar)
    if aLocalVar is 0 then return ""
    if aLocalVar is not 0 then return " - substring"
end subTern
```